# Passing a JavaScript object from my form to my Node app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have this jQuery code that gets data from my form. I used a console statement to see the value. However I want to pass the data to my Node application so that I can insert into a database.

```
$(function() {
    $('#kiosk_signin').submit(function() {
    var data = $('#kiosk_signin :input').serializeArray();
    console.log(data[0]);
    });
});
```

Please let me know what I need to do.

Comment: does it matter that im using express instead of http?

Comment: you need to start by building a node.js application that will accept POST requests. If you have already done so, the next step would be to perform an ajax request that sends the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using express, posting this to your route.., and inserting into the DB..

You would do something like this in your routes..

```
router.post('/whereever', function(req,res,next(){
    ///assuming kiosk_signin is the name of an input field
    ///and the action is ='/whereever' method='post'
    var data = req.body.kiosk_signin
    console.log('if you want to log it', data)
    db.insert({propert: data}).then(function(){
        res.redirect('/home')
    })
})
```

I don't use JQuery for submitting forms if I have a full-stack app, just because I intend on sending it directly to the server.  Hopefully that helps..

Comment: kiosk_signin is the id of the form. field names are textboxfirstname, textboxlastname, etc

Comment: I was using jQuery for form validation and when the document is submitted. I wanted to pass the data to the server for processing. I didn't want the client to process the database because of numerous client side issues.